# Please help to replace these words: working environment, disseminate, disperse, person above in the hierarchy, and fundamental.

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

please help to provide the synonym or phrase for the words, that are of a higher learning order, below:

1. working environment
2. spread/pass on/disseminate (knowledge from supervisors to subordinates)
3. disperse/stop and discontinue (meeting)
4. person above in the hierarchy (not supervisor or manager) [looking for the opposite for "subordinate"]
5. fundamental (knowledge)
6. expedite (process or procedure)

*the words in brackets are helping words to provide contexts.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello, chelsia. Unless reasons not to do so are given, many people here suspect that these sorts of lists of questions conceal a 'Please do my homework for me' motive, which would not be something ELU would be happy doing.

Comment: Sorry, but i do now understand what you are trying to say. Are you trying to say that "ELU would be happy to help if reasons are given and with the underlying motive?" Perhaps, a sentence that is easier to understand? Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the requirements etc for questions, given in the Help Center? I'd guess the person who close-voted thought the question**s** inappropriate for ELU too.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. workspace
2. impart (information)
3. adjourn
4. authority
5. constitution/ethics
6. expedite